# What can I do to deploy only changed microservices if I keep all of them in one git monorepo?

Tags: git, gradle, continuous-integration, microservices, monorepo

So, I have one git monorepo and several microservices inside it. Each microservice is a gradle module with Java/Kotlin code - a submodule of the root gradle project.
I'm wondering how to configure CI/CD to deploy only changed microservices?

Comment: Are the microservices 100% separate, meaning that they don't even use a shared library, from the same monorepo?

Comment: They do use shared code that is also placed in this monorepo.

Comment: So when you say "changed microservice", you actually mean "the microservice itself, or any of the code it relies on from other parts of the monorepo has changed"? I can tell you this is going to be a nightmare to get to 100% correct. Why not just deploy everything as a package?

Comment: Any of the code it relies too.

> Why not just deploy everything as a package?
Because I want to be able to deploy services independently - it's more flexible.

Comment: Flexibility has a cost. You've just encountered it; decide now whether you wish to pay it, or not, and go from there.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking it)
Trying to find a good enough way to solve the problem with deployments.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a mapping of source directories/files to services.
- Store the commit of currently deployed services.
- On CI/CD run, get the changeset of all files that were changed to previously deployed code.
- Deploy only services that have changed source files according to the mapping.

Comment: As far as we care about changed files in modules-dependencies it will work if there is a way/tool to automatically generate this mapping (to grab all sources including dependencies for the module).
Do you know such?

Comment: That would depend on the build tool.  I know of at least one SBT plugin (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pull-request-validator) which builds a list of all projects which have changed or depend on a project which changed, so something similar could probably be implemented as a plugin to your build tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jib, I added this PR (https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/pull/3641) that will let you know which images were actually built+pushed.

So in your monorepo you would say go build/deploy everything, then you use that flag to figure out which ones were pushed. Couple that feature with -Djib.skipExistingImages and you get jib pushing out only images that